# How to add arrows to elements with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I have a navbar that contains a Search field and a Social Network dropdown which both show up below the navbar if they are active.
I saw on other websites small "arrows" that connect the second row elements visually with the first one like this:
[image]

How can I achieve the same and always make sure that the arrow is also pointing to the correct parent element (visually)?
This is my navbar (somehow the JavaScript doesn't work): https://play.tailwindcss.com/qksxyrh24P

Answer (score 3):

1>>create a div with same height and width and rotate it by 45 deg.

2>>make it's postion absolute z indiex of 2 and same color as your dropdown field

3>> make sure to add some space between your search field and dropdownfield

4>> use top left properties to place it appropriatly

5>> then just add show class that you are using to show or hide the dropdown `link`

https://jsfiddle.net/t5mfs1hy/

Comment: But how to make sure that the arrow always points to the right origin? Can you show it in the linked playground?

Comment: okk added a fiddle code example

Comment: Thanks, but if you change the width of the content window you can see that the arrow is moving around or even breaking the line if it gets too narrow.

Comment: so just change the value of top left and right as per your requirments.if you dont about this than you can refer this[link]https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp

Comment: This is not a Tailwind example